# rails-portfolio gem not working with rails-5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

i m using [rails-portfolio](https://github.com/messutied/rails-portfolio) my ruby version is 2.3.1 and rails version is 5.1.4 
after adding `gem 'rails-portfolio'` and on running bundle install it gives following error:-
even on running `bundle update` is shows same error on console without any luck

> Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":   In
>   snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
>       rails (= 5.1.4)
>
> In Gemfile:
>       rails (~> 5.1.4)
>
> ```
> rails-portfolio (~> 0.0.5) was resolved to 0.0.5, which depends on
>   rails (~> 4.2)
> ```
>
> Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using
>   only the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to downgrade your Rails version, *or* you could fork the Gem, modify `portfolio.gemspec` to reflect your version and hope it acts as expected — a quick inspection indicates shows that there's nothing glaring  obviously that would break.